# MySQL Normalization with Category with 1st Tier Sub-Category and 2nd Tier Sub-Category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am learning normalization in database for web design and I cannot find the answer that I need. I was able to start with some tutorials I found online but cannot find answers that I can understand.

I have several product categories such as: Electronics, Appliances. (we'll call them "categories").

Electronics itself has sub-categories: Cell Phones, Computers, Tablets. ("1st tier category")

Then Cell Phones has its own category: Smartphones, Tablet Phones, etc. ("2nd tier category")

So currently I have tables as such:

```
Categories table
------------------------------------------
|    category_id     |   category_name   |
------------------------------------------
|          1         |     Electronics   |
|          2         |     Appliances    |
------------------------------------------

1st tier categories table
------------------------------------------
|    category_id     |   1st_tier_name   |
------------------------------------------
|          1         |     Cell phones   |
|          1         |      Computers    |
|          1         |       Tablets     |
------------------------------------------
```

Here is where I'm stuck. How do I create the 2nd tier categories table and how would I make a link table that works in this case? Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: This appears to be a question about hierarchical data

Comment: Using separate tables for tree structure is not a good idea generally. All of these are categories, so they should be stored in one table, have a unique primary key, like category_id, and parent_id which can be null or other category id. This way you get primary categories by selecting all categories where parent_id is null, and a subcategory where parent_id is an category_id of parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parent_id to specify to which category the record belongs:

```
+--------+---------------+-----------+
| cat_id | name          | parent_id |
+--------+---------------+-----------+
|      1 | Electronics   |         0 |
|      2 | Appliances    |         0 |
|      3 | Cell phones   |         1 |
|      4 | Computers     |         1 |
|      5 | Tablets       |         1 |
|      6 | Smartphones   |         3 |
|      7 | Tablet Phones |         3 |
+--------+---------------+-----------+
```

To select the needed data you can improve on a query like :

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> a.name AS main_category,
    -> b.name AS second_level_category,
    -> c.name AS thrid_level_category
    ->  FROM categories AS a
    -> LEFT JOIN categories AS b ON (a.cat_id=b.parent_id)
    -> LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON (b.cat_id=c.parent_id)
    -> WHERE a.parent_id=0;
+---------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| main_category | second_level_category | thrid_level_category |
+---------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Electronics   | Cell phones           | Smartphones          |
| Electronics   | Cell phones           | Tablet Phones        |
| Electronics   | Computers             | NULL                 |
| Electronics   | Tablets               | NULL                 |
| Appliances    | NULL                  | NULL                 |
+---------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

@last comment:

```
mysql> desc categories;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cat_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table categories\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: categories
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This allows for reuse of your category code (instead of writing two sets of models or handlers for each tier).

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me how exactly tables a b and c should be structured? And is 'categories' the first table you provided?

Comment: @user3117155 there is a single table, categories which joins with itself. a,b,c are it's aliases.

Comment: Can you draw me a table of how "categories" should look?

Comment: @user3117155 added create table statement and desc

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been very confusing and stressful and you are my savior. Thank you for being so patient with me!